# Youtube Iframe inside Meteor template

Tags: javascript, iframe, meteor, youtube-api

I am trying to make youtube iframe within template and call that template from multiple pages. I am able to load video on first page load (regardless of from where do I call `player` template) but as soon as I navigate from one page that have `player` template to another, iframe dom is deleted and won't load again until refresh.

My initial assumption why it's breaking is because `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is being called only once and iron-router is cashing dom elements.

**Template**:

```
<template name="player">
  <div class="template-banner">
    <div class="video-container" id="player">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Template JS**

```
downloadIFrameAPI = _.once(->
  Meteor.startup ->
    $.getScript '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
    return
  return
)
Player =
  create: (playerId, videoTemplate, video) ->
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = ->
      console.log 'creating player...'
      window.player = new (YT.Player)(playerId,
        width: '560'
        height: '349'
        events:
          onReady: ->
            console.log 'Player Loaded'
            Player.loadVideo(video)
      )
      videoTemplate.rendered = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady

    downloadIFrameAPI()
  loadVideo: (video) ->
    player.loadVideoByUrl
      mediaContentUrl: video


Template.player.onRendered ->
  Player.create 'player', Template.player, this.data.video
```

Comment: You have the player being created inside a `Template.player.onRendered` callback. Meteor will not re-render templates that it doesn't feel are necessary to re-render when a user navigates around a site. So your code is only being called once when the `player` template initially renders.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny When I navigate around the site, I can see that console log is showing 'creating player...' which is in create method